# SSDT & redgate source control - how to link?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, redgate

We currently have our database objects in TFS2012 and happily use redgate sql source control to check in & getlatest. So far this works great.

I now want to use SSDT in order to create a dacpac that defines the latest schema.

What I'm missing is how to link the SQL Server database project so that a check-in via redgate source control would ripple through to the database project (upon a getlatest) and therefore schema changes would be shown in the dacpac  upon a recompile?

thanks

Comment: I've tried the beta of Red Gate's SQL Source control and it's never quite worked to integrate well with SSDT. It's a lot better than the release version, though. You may want to hit up Red-Gate's support to see if you can get access to the SSC beta that ties to SQL Projects. The only major issues I've seen are: Permissions are always pulled in - can't exclude them; the folder structure only works with the newer SQL Project structure, not with those upgraded from DB Projects.  (so overall not too bad, but makes it impractical for our older projects.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's 3+ months after I posted the question, and https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ I guess I should state what the outcome was...

We had a number of unresolved (at the time at least) issues automating SQL Compare, which was the reason for looking into SSDT in the first place. The more we looked at SSDT the more we became impressed with it (still has *some* issues, but doesn't everything?) to the extent that we have now dropped our use of redgate, therefore the need for SSDT to play nicely with redgate is no longer required.

This is not to say we're not a fan of Redgates products or that the answer is to drop redgates products - just that they didn't meet our requirements when our requirements changed (we started to automate everything).

I'll still be sending Redgate a Christmas card, honest :)

Comment: Essentially, you stopped using SQL source control?

Comment: @Sebazzz - dropped redgate products yes. SQL code is still in source control but using SSDT instead. I would have thought redgate have resolved our original issues by now (they *are* a quality outfit with plenty of smart cookies after all) but since we've switched I'm a *big* fan of SSDT. This Q  was from 5 years ago - redgates beta linking to SSDT didn't come out a few months afterwards - as mentioned by David Atkinsons answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a document](http://assets.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/learn-more/assets/redgate-tools-and-db-projects.pdf) describing how to use SQL Source Control and SQL Compare in conjunction with SSDT database projects. It's beta functionality, and we're aware of a few issues, but please report them to us (support@red-gate.com) so we can prioritize our backlog.